# Android Build.gradle DuplicateFileException Error

Tags: android, gradle

So I'm trying to incorporate `Firebase SDK` in android studio and I followed the documentation to the letter. Here is my Error and `Gradle` File. Any help Appreciated, thanks.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.firebase/firebase-client-jvm/pom.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\RealChatHusk\app\libs\firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Owner.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.firebase\firebase-client-jvm\2.5.2\91731b8f5868a3e8a8a773f29b8d06b5c358f5bb\firebase-client-jvm-2.5.2.jar

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.owner.realchathusk"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'` Then Clean-Rebuild Your Project.

Comment: Same error occurs after this fix

Answer (score 1):

Add below text on build.gradle file solve problem

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude  'build-data.properties'
 }
```

If getting more error DuplicateFileException add file with exclude.
Like :

Error

```
Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
```

Solution

```
exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```